# How to count array elements across filtered records in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have DynamoDB records using this structure, category being the partition key:

```js
{ 'category':'1',
  'name' : 'wind instruments',
  'instruments' : [
    { 'name' : 'oboe',
      'count' : 3 },
    { 'name' : 'recorder',
      'count' : 2 },
    { 'name' : 'trumpet',
      'count' : 2} ]
}

{ 'category':'1',
  'name' : 'string instruments',
  'instruments' : [
    { 'name' : 'violin',
      'count' : 6 },
    { 'name' : 'cello',
      'count' : 3 } ]
}
```

I would like to run the following queries on this DynamoDB table :

- how many kinds of instrument do I have ? (answer is 5)
- how many instruments do I have in total ? (answer is 16)

By either using :

- AWS CLI
- PartiQL
- Python code

Thanks for your help !

side note: please do not suggest any change in the data model, it's designed like this on purpose (The app reading the instruments inventory per instrument category is the principal access pattern).

Comment: Presumably `name` is the sort key of your table. You'd have to query for all items with category 1 and then client-side aggregation of the instrument types (sum of the length of `instruments` for each returned item) and instruments (sum of the `count` values for each instrument in `instruments` for each returned item).

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not do these types of queries for you, there is no count or distinct for example. My suggestion is to either have an aggregate table or store aggregate data back to the table. To do this you would use [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| pk       | sk          | instruments           |  inst_kind  | inst_type |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| category1 | wind        | map of instrumnets    |             |           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| category1 | string      | map of instruments    |             |           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| category1 | aggregate   |                       |   5         |  16       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To update the aggregates you use Streams and Lambda and adjust the values each time you modify the item.

To retrieve the aggregates, you simply do a `GetItem` where PK = "{categoryId}" and SK = "aggreagate"